# VB.NET: How to move Objects randomly with smooth flow

Tags: vb.net

I just coded something that can move the object randomly by every timer tick. I would like to move the object smoothly(not jumping into random coordinates). How to code that? Btw. this is my code to randomly move the objects

```
Label2.Location = New Point(Rnd.Next(0, Me.Width - Label2.Width), Rnd.Next(0, 
Me.Height - (Label2.Height + (Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height))))    
Me.Text = "X:" & Label2.Location.X & ", Y:" & Label2.Location.Y
```

Comment: You can use looping to move the object. Increase or decrease the object's position by 1 in every loop

Comment: Can I use random function for random movement? how to limit the random to -1 to 1 ?